# What is the cause of error MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql, performance, select, mariadb

I use latest version wordpress and after save post, admin session end and auto logout from dashboard and cannot login again ...

Error log showing following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ORDER BY menu_order ASC' at line 3 SELECT ID FROM wp_posts
                    WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
                    AND ID in ()
                    ORDER BY menu_order ASC quire('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/goodnews/single.php'), mom_single_post_content, mom_single_post_format
```

Please advise

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The problem is 
`ID IN ()`
You have to specify which values of ID you want to select writing them between brackets (separating them with commas). Otherwise if don't have to put a filter on ID values delete ID IN () from the WHERE.

Comment: this problem in wordprss base and should be edite code !?

Comment: I don't know how wordpress works, sorry...I just commented the error message on the query and that query can't work. It wasn't my intention to be out of thread (if so).